# Best resources to learn MVC, Linq, Entity Framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-4

I ll soon be joining a new team where they are working in technologies mentioned above. I am coming from asp.net background and havent worked much in any of these tech. 
Please suggest good resources to go thru and which one to start learning first.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For getting up to speed on MVC and EF, you may want to check out Microsoft's 10-part tutorial.  Here's the link to [part 1](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application).

It doesn't seem like a bad tutorial series.

That series also has LINQ scattered in it, but you may also want to download [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) and the samples that come with it to really get into LINQ.  On top of that, LINQPad is a great code snippet compiler, so you don't have to fire up Visual Studio to test out some short bits of code.

Lastly, [Hooked On LINQ](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/MainPage.ashx) has a number of resources directed right at learning LINQ from the beginning.  It's not a bad resource, either.

Good luck on the new project.  Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 for LinqPad - it's probably the best free tool I have ever used.

Comment: @MikeGoodwin Yep - LINQPad is a tool a use almost every day.  It rocks.

Comment: Me too. Word of advice though  - definitely invest the few dollars in the paid for version. It includes Intellisense, which makes things sooo much easier. "It's like turning a light on in a darkened room" to quote someone or other.

Answer (score 0):

the official asp.net website has a section for mvc where you can get good foundation to start learning those technologies. I am sure if you look on amazon or some other bookstore for books regarding those technologies you'll get many results with quality books for beginners. 
I did use the wrox books for MVC, and I earned fair amount of knowledge from those books.

Answer (score 0):

Steven Sandersons book on MVC is superb in my opinion. His MVC 3 one is here

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Pro-ASP-NET-MVC-Framework-3rd/dp/1430234040/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1327434969&sr=8-1

But he also has one for MVC 2 and (I think) MVC 1.

The reason I like them so much is that he takes you though building a sample application, but in a proper commercially sound way. It's not a Hello World app, it has good engineering practises built in and is complex enough to be like working on your first real project without overpowering you.

E.g. it uses dependency injection, unit testing (in fact it is developed in a test driven development way in the book), shows how to make good clean URLs, etc.

Really excellent book.